# No artifacts deployed with jenkins gradle artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I try to use jenkins pipeline to upload gradle artifacts to the maven repository. 
I have followed  [Working With Pipeline Jobs in Jenkins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins)

As mentioned in the referenced document, the `rtGradle.run` shall deploy build artifacts to the artifactory. However, no build artifacts are deployed in my case.

I have checked the content of `buildInfo.getDeployableArtifacts` and figured out that it is empty.

Following some hints, I have put the following code to my `build.gradle`:

```
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                artifact file("bmo-interface-common/build/libs/bmo-interface-common-${version}.jar")
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the previous doesn't help and still no artifact is deployed.

Where is the problem? What do I miss?

Thanks for any input.

**EDIT**

I have forget to add server setting for the gradle deployer. With this setting the deployment was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have forget to add server setting for the gradle deployer. With this setting the deployment was successful" please add this as an answer and put it as the right answer.